# Module won't run in Excel VBA editor

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a program in excel's Visual Studio editor but when I click the green run button nothing happens and the module doesn't run. However, with other modules it is running fine. I am not sure what the issue is.

I have already tried restarting excel and copying the code to another file and module that work but the same issue occurs.

This is the code:

```
Sub Balance()
    Dim rownum As Long
    Dim colnum As Long
    Dim startrow As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long

    rownum = 1
    colnum = 1
    lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a" & lastrow)
        For rownum = 1 To lastrowEmp
            Do
                If .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "Employee Group Totals" Then
                    startrow = rownum
                End If

                rownum = rownum + 1
                If (rownum > lastrow) Then Exit For
            Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "Net pay"

            endrow = rownum
            rownum = rownum + 1

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(startrow & ":" & 
      endrow).EntireRow.Copy

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Range("A1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        Next rownum
    End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: what is lastrowEmp? it seems like a typo

Comment: Your Macro is Running, but it skips the For Loop. Run it using `F8` ...you will see for yourself because of the Variable `lastrowEmp`, it doesn't have any value.

Comment: i'd recommend using option explicit at top of code

Comment: I get the VtC's, but this is a _great_ object lesson on `Option Explicit` and is very valuable for `VBA` new programmers. Hope it stays open. (Unless it's closed as a dupe of one of the myriad of other "you've got a typo in your variable name, use `Option Explicit`" questions...)

Answer (score 6):

**Use this:**

```
For rownum = 1 To lastrow
```

**Instead of:**

```
For rownum = 1 To lastrowEmp
```

Also, it's wise to use `Option Explicit` before any subject, to avoid these mistakes.

Your code is running, but as there is no value in `lastrowEmp` the For Loop is skipped.